# Sensor for low-amplitude, fast current pulse?

Tags: sensor, current-measurement, high-frequency

I am trying to find a way to measure low-amplitude, fast current pulses in wires ranging from ~1-5 mm in diameter, preferably using a non-contact method. The current pulses are typically around 50 mA amplitude and have a width of ~300 ns (I estimate the sensor would need a bandwidth of at least 200 MHz).

I have been looking into Rogowski coils as a possible option; however, they typically seem to be designed for larger currents (>10 A). Does such a high-sensitivity non-contact current sensor that I am looking for exist?

**Edit:** The reason I am looking for a non-contact sensor is because we want to measure the current pulses on a high-voltage line (>10 kV), which would seem to rule out contact-based methods such as measuring the voltage across a shunt resistor.

Comment: Pearson makes current transformers that would work for this.

Comment: Is a series resistor as a sensing element not an option?

Comment: @LordTeddy we have done that in some cases for the ground side of the system. However, we would also like to get a measure of the current on the HV side of the system, which has voltages exceeding 10 kV. So that might make use of a series shunt resistor more problematic. This is why I'm ideally looking for a non-contact sensor.

Comment: @Time4Tea that's fair, but possibly information to be included in your question, along with anything else you've ruled out.

Comment: @LordTeddy ok, I will add that info to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, low-power wireless transmission is widely available. If the setup is for a lab experiment and not a product, then a series shunt and a wireless node may be the simplest way to go. The wireless node may be as simple as a couple AA batteries, a shunt amplifier, a V->I driver, and an infrared LED. It doesn't need a microprocessor nor RF circuitry. You could make it out of a dozen or two discrete transistors :)

For a product, everything depends on how accessible those 10kV lines are. If you can manage to shine light on them, then a simple supercapacitor-powered node with optical output and a solar cell will work great and last a decade at least, with the LED illuminator being the primary life-limiting part. The main power hog will be the wideband amplifier with its requisite high bias, whether discrete or in integrated form.

A shunt resistor can also be coupled via a 10kV-rated pulse isolation transformer. Maybe you'd need to get a custom one made.

Otherwise, a Rogowski coil is a perfect solution. They work great with nanosecond pulses, never mind 100s-of-nanosecond ones. As one commenter hinted - [Pearson Electronics](https://www.pearsonelectronics.com/products/wideband-current-monitors) makes ready-to-use Rogowski coils with plenty of bandwidth for your application. Remember to terminate them with 50Ωs for calibrated output.

The wire will need to be inside of a long rigid insulating sleeve passed through the inside of the coil, to prevent dielectric breakdown or high leakage. Or the wire may be insulated well enough to be touch-safe, then the insulating sleeve is not necessary as long as the wire can be positioned so that it doesn't ever contact the coil enclosure, to prevent damage from rubbing.

> I have been looking into Rogowski coils as a possible option; however, they typically seem to be designed for larger currents (>10 A). Does such a high-sensitivity non-contact current sensor that I am looking for exist?

You aren't interested as much in maximum current, but sensitivity, so focus the search on that. High maximum current capacity doesn't hurt your application, and you simply don't care about it.

1V/A wideband Rogowski coils are what you're looking for. The output will be 50mV into a 50Ω load - plenty of signal to amplify cleanly to whatever amplitude you need for data acquisition.

Rogowski coil manufacturers will usually gladly make a higher-sensitivity coil to best suit your application, if you'd want that. It all depends on the budget and how serious you are when talking to them.